# Win8 IE10 HTML5 Drag & Drop - reporting bad clientX / clientY coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a simple demo where my goal is to drag & drop an element onto a canvas element, for the purpose of drawing something on the canvas at that exact location. I have this working almost everywhere, however, Win8 IE10 is reporting strange `clientX/clientY` mouse coordinates within the drop event.

[Here is the demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/bradgreens/pen/QbpLdo), where I can replicate inconsistent coordinates between IE10 and the rest.

You'll notice in IE10, the coordinates are very different than the other browsers. I'd like to resolve this demo so that the coordinates are consistent in all modern browsers including IE10, but am stuck.

My pattern uses this [cross-browser mouse coordinates](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/) example.

Code:

HTML

```
<div class="draggable-element"></div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

CSS

```
.draggable-element {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery is loaded)

```
'use strict';

var $el = $('.draggable-element');
$el[0].draggable = true;

var $canvas = $('canvas');

$canvas.on('dragover', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

$canvas.on('drop', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var targetRectangle = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  var coords = {
    x: event.originalEvent.clientX - targetRectangle.left,
    y: event.originalEvent.clientY - targetRectangle.top };

  alert('x: ' + coords.x + ', y: ' + coords.y);
});
```

**Update:**
Upon further testing, this bug appears to exist in Win8 IE10 specifically. I'll update if I learn more.

Comment: For what it's worth, if anyone tests Win8 IE10 and finds this works perfectly... let me know...

Comment: I am observing the same type of problems. Did you ever figure out a workaround?